# How to alert selected options from particular select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code on internet. It simply alerts options that are selected from  element.

I have multiple  elements, and I need an information from a particular one, let's say the one with id "one". How can I add this restriction to my code.

```
$("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
          str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
     alert(str);
  })
  .trigger("change");
```

Thanks

Comment: you want to display the selected text over a particular item?

Comment: no, alert in popup. I edited to make more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want that jQuery to run for the  element with ID "one", add the ID selector:

```
$("select#one").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select#one option:selected").each(function () {
          str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
     alert(str);
})
.trigger("change");
```

Comment: thanks, i tried putting id selector before "select" and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
$("select option:selected").each(function () {
```

to

```
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function () {
```